# How to edit link that show modal box in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem where I try to show a modal box, it's when I append some a href="" links to my  that is on my index page.

I have this in my jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a').click(function () { 
    // Dialog   
    $("#feed"+$(this).attr('id')).dialog({
      bgiframe: true,
      width: 400,
      modal: true
    });
  return false;
  });
});
```

And this is the link I have on the index page:

```
<p><a href="#" id="0">Feed 0</a></p>
```

If I add the links on the index page it works, but if I empty my div and post new links without any reload they stop to work. No modal box shows, how can I make the jQuery get that the links are there even if they apere after the document is loaded?

I need a jQuery function that allows me to add links after the document has been loaded.

Thanks in Advance
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach a handler to `document` that'll work on current *and* future links, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').live('click', function () { 
    $("#feed"+this.id).dialog({
      bgiframe: true,
      width: 400,
      modal: true
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

As an aside, your `id`'s aren't valid in HTML4 (they can't start with a number, not that they'll realistically cause any issues here, just pointing it out).  They *are* valid in HTML5 however :)